# New mobile web site

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mobile-website

I am creating a new website that needs to work in desktop browsers as well on mobile devices. I am using VS2010, MS SQL 2008, IIS 7, EF4 and .NET 4.

I have several questions:

1. Which is better MVC or Web Form? (why)
2. Web App or Website?
3. Should I do it as 2 sites or combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. on .net 4 you can use either, since webforms come with outing support. but, don't use .net controls. If you already know MVC go for MVC
2. Personally I prefer website. Easy to edit when you are away from vs. It compiles on run time anyway
3. Is you use MVC you can just plug-in another view to your current site with some device detection such as DeviceAtlas